# QML not showing proper graphics after I set QT_QUICK_BACKEND

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I'm trying to deploy a `QT/QML` app on windows. The app works fine on my development environment but when i deploy it on a VM Windows machine, it didn't shows GUI so i traced the problem using Microsoft [DebugView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/debugview) and found a [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68154514/qt-qt-6-1-1-failed-to-create-vertex-shader-error-0x80070057)

By simply placing the below line, the problem is partially removed as now I can see GUI on my VM machine as well

```
qputenv("QT_QUICK_BACKEND","software");
```

But the gui has missing components i.e improper `TextField` shown below

[image]

If i comment out the above mentioned `QT_QUICK_BACKEND` line, the gfx is properly shown on my development machine but then it doesn't show gfx on my VM machine

[image]

What is causing this issue, and how should I resolve this problem ?

Comment: That makes it sound like it can't find the direct3d libraries, so you have to tell it to use the software backend.

Comment: @JarMan: When i use "QT_QUICK_BACKEND", the gfx are messed up as shown in the above screenshot. Alternatively, if i don't use it, the gfx doesn't show up on other machines, it only is visible on my development machine. Would appreciate help in this regard. thanks

Comment: Yeah, I don't know why it looks messed up, but you don't want to use the software backend if you can help it. You need to figure out why it can't find the libraries it needs for the normal (direct3d?) backend. Might need to add an environment variable to tell it where to find them. I'm not a Windows expert, so I don't know for sure.

Comment: Because it is a VM, and, because you're using Qt, have you tried Linux instead of Windows?

Comment: @StephenQuan: I've build the app on windows 10 machine and trying to deploye on another Windows 10 (VM) and Windows server 2012 R2 (VPS), doesn't work on both of these machine

Comment: For barebones machines, you typically have modern graphics cards with decent OpenGL support. Because you're talking about a virtual environment the graphics driver is often virtual. Try setting the "QT_OPENGL" environment variable to "software". Also, you may have luck with changing the Graphics settings. I still recommend you test your app in Linux, since, you may find on the same VM environment, you get better/different experience.

Comment: @StephenQuan: I'm deploying this app on win10 VM. On the win10 VM, i have set this environment variable i.e. "QSG_RHI_PREFER_SOFTWARE_RENDERER=1" which solved the issue on windows 10 VM but the problem still exist when i try to deploy the app on Windows Server 2012 R2 (VPS).